# Argument of Complex Number (Am I wrong?)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

I'm given $z=-2+\sqrt{3}i$. So I worked out the argument of $arg(z)=\tan^{-1}(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{-2})$. I got the answer $2.256$rad. But the given answer is $2.45$rad. Am I wrong?

Comment: Pretty sure it needs to be 2.427868

Comment: Can I know how you get it ?

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ArcTan2%28sqrt%283%29%2C-2%29

Comment: Why my calculator is different ?

Comment: Your argument is not in the interval $(-\pi,\pi]$ as should be. The *main value* is really $\approx -0.716\,724$.

Answer (score 1):

You have computed $$\tan^{-1}\left(-\sqrt{\frac32}\right)$$

Comment: Thanks! I got it . Yea I did a mistake